# What is "G-d spoke one thing, I heard two, for G-d has strength"?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

Tehillim 62:12
Other than Rashi's I have heard another person say this verse means Hashem's words are so powerful that from one statement we will receive more than one message. Could anyone explain this verse?

Rashi:
I heard two things from it, and what are the two things? First, that G-d has strength to repay a man according to his deed. Second, that You, O L-rd, have kindness. Now, from which statement do we derive this? From the second commandment of the Decalogue. We derive from it that the Holy One, blessed be He, punishes iniquity and preserves kindness, as it is stated therein: “I visit the iniquity of the fathers upon the children, etc.” Therefore, I am confident that He will pay a good reward to the righteous and punishment to the wicked. I learned from the work of Rabbi Moshe Hadarshan, but our Sages interpreted it as referring to [the maxim that] “Remember” and “Keep” were stated in a single utterance.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for a source for your first suggestion, or are you looking for any explanation other than Rashi?

Comment: I'm asking for other explanation or some elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Rashi to Exodus 20:8 provides an alternative explanation (translation mine):

> [The obligation to] "Remember" [the Sabbath], and [the obligation to] "Guard" [the Sabbath] (Deuteronomy 5:12) were said at once. Likewise, "One who violates [the Sabbath] will be put to death" (Exodus 31:14) and "On the day of the Sabbath two sheep [shall be brought as an offering]" (Numbers 28:9). Likewise, "Don't wear a mixture [of wool and linen]" (Deuteronomy 22:11) and "Tassels shall you make for yourselves [on the four corners of your garments]" (Ibid. v. 12). Likewise, "The nakedness of your brother's wife [you shall not uncover]" (Leviticus 18:16) and "The *yavam* shall have relations with her" (Deuteronomy 25:5). This is what is stated (Psalms 62:12), "One G-d has spoken, two have I heard."

According to this Rashi, the verse in Psalms alludes to these various instances where G-d spoke once but said two different things (*two have I heard*). As this is something only G-d can do, He can appropriately be called "full of strength."

Comment: Thanks so much - may i know how did you find this? Just want to learn how to reach an indirect rashi reference. @DonielF

Comment: I happened to recognize the passuk quoted as being related to Zachor v'shamor b'dibur echad, and so I pulled up that Rashi. Indeed, I had remembered correctly.